# How to implement an edit approval queue in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am attempting to make it so a user can edit displayed info stored in an object but that edit is not displayed publicly until an admin approves the edit. These edits are stored in a queue that an admin can sort through.
For example:

```
class examplemodel(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField()
```

This charfield is displayed on a template somewhere where a user can click a link, letting the text become a form containing the same info which when the form is submitted, sends the info not back into the database but to a queue to be approved on the admin page. The only way I can think to do this right now is to make a editRequest object that lets me have the form create a different object and then have some approval function that updates the old object if approved. In which case, how would I tie this to the admin page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to create a new model `ApprovalPendingUsers` with required fields and also add `ForeignKey` for user in that model. You can also add `created_time` and `last_modified_time` fields for sorting. When user submit edit form details store everything in your new model with user `ForeignKey`.

```
#import User Model
from apps.users.models import BaseUserModel 

class ApprovalPendingUsersModel (Models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(BaseUserModel)
    # Other fields.
```

Create a list view for admin and return all rows of your new model to view.

```
class ApprovalPendingUsersListView(ListView):
    # template_name and context_object_name 

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ApprovalPendingUsersModel.objects.all()
```

When admin click on approval button replace `BaseUserModel` details with `ApprovalPendingUsersModel` and delete that row from `ApprovalPendingUsersModel`.

Use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) to avoid creation of many `ApprovalPendingUsersModel` rows when user give more than one update requests.

Comment: thank! that what I figured I would have t do, just wanted to see if there was some django functionality for this built in somewhere